# Has a prisoner ever been sentenced to death for murder (or other actions) while incarcerated?

Tags: death, prison

This is inspired by discussions around the game Prison Architect. A lot of players find themselves frustrated with certain prisoners and wanting to have them transferred to death row.

Has this ever happened in real life - has a prisoner has committed murder while incarcerated and been sentenced to death for it?

Ideally I'm looking for recent (20th/21st century) examples in the US, though will take any example where some attempt at a rule of law was followed. I'm not counting people being imprisoned and suddenly dying, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this list](https://deathpenaltyinfo.org/state-and-federal-info/federal-death-penalty/list-of-federal-death-row-prisoners), there are at least nine people on death row in federal prisons for killing a fellow inmate. Since there are many more people in state prisons, I assume there are even more people on death row in state prisons. Unfortunately, the only lists I found that included state prisons were woefully incomplete (ie, the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_death_row_inmates_in_the_United_States) list of people on death row doesn't have the people on this list.)

Comment: And I would suspect that killing a guard would be even more likely to draw such a sentence (although the offense is likely somewhat less likely to succeed)